# Proof Concerning Sum of Binomial Coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Could anybody provide a proof of the following identity identity:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1+n}{n}=\binom{2N-1}{N}$$

possibly using Symmetry property and Pascal's rule (or another easier way):

$$\binom{a}{b}=\binom{a-1}{b-1}+\binom{a-1}{b}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=0}^N {N+k \choose N} &=& \sum_{k=0}^N {N-1+k \choose N-1} + \sum_{k=-1}^{N-1} {N+k \choose N} \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} {N-1+k \choose N-1} + \sum_{k=0}^N {N+k \choose N} + {2N-1 \choose N-1} - {2N \choose N}
\end{eqnarray}$$

So

$$\begin{eqnarray}
0 &=& \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} {N-1+k \choose N-1} + {2N-1 \choose N-1} - {2N \choose N} \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} {N-1+k \choose N-1} - {2N - 1 \choose N}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $${2N-1 \choose N}$$ is the number of ways to choose $N$ distinct numbers from the set $\{1,2,\ldots, 2N-1\}$. Group the possibilities by the largest of these $N$ numbers.  This largest number is at least $N$.  For $k \in \{0, \ldots, N-1\}$ there are $${N - 1 + k \choose N-1}$$ cases where the largest number is $N+k$. So

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} {N-1+k \choose k} = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} {N-1+k \choose N-1} = {2N-1 \choose N}.$$

Comment: Would have preferred if it was a bit more mathematical than intuitive, but this works too.